# What do you call this dark grey arch?

Tags: html, github, jsfiddle

Has anyone ever experienced something like this before? I don't even know what you would call it.

When editing in jsfiddle, its fine

**image: [everything is fine]**

[image]

But when I view it on my website there is some type of arch.

**[strange dark line]**

[image]

Has anyone ever experienced this before?

Comment: Provide actual code

Comment: use developer tool to check where it from(in chrome press f12)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely jsfiddle applies a default margin/padding that helps hide the background image (the arc) in question. Or, simpler, there is no CSS on jsfiddle.

Check if there is any sort of background image (perhaps from CSS) being used on your website.